# Modeling a Poll Feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I'm developing a poll feature that allows `users` to create poll `questions` with `options` and allow other `users` to `answer` them

The `answer` model includes an `option_id` column but the two models are not related.

I have two questions:

- Do my models (below) fully encapsulate what I'm trying to represent?
- How would the create method for an `answer` controller action look? (Specifically, how to retrieve the `option_id`)

Note: I've never dealt with this pattern in which a model(`answer`) references another model (`option`) via `option_id` but the two aren't related

So far I have this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :options
  has_many :answers
end

class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [tut](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/build-a-jquery-mobile-survey-app-rails-setup/) for a mobile app doing this